# Is there a difference between tf.nn.conv1d and tf.nn.convolution in Tensorflow?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, convolution

I want to know what is the difference between a these two. For me, they are the same function, so I do not see the reason of existance two same functions.

Answer (score 0):

In TensorFlow 2, they accept different arguments:

> `tf.nn.convolution(input,...)`
>
> Computes sums of N-D convolutions (actually cross-correlation).
>
> `input`: An (N+2)-D Tensor of type T, of shape [batch_size] + input_spatial_shape + [in_channels]

While the second one is more specific:

> `tf.nn.conv1d(input,...)`
>
> Computes a 1-D convolution given 3-D input and filter tensors.
>
> `input`: A 3D Tensor.input: A 3D Tensor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, basically, both in some case, e.g. 3D tensor input, are computing the same thing?

Comment: I don't know for sure. I believe you can check it by feeding a 3D tensor to both.